# command to capture current command prompt text

Tags: bash

I'm using https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt to customize my bash prompt. so, my prompt usually looks something like this

`✔ ~/dotfiles [master|⚑ 1]
15:00 $`

is there any command with which I can capture that prompt text? I want the `[master|⚑ 1]` text without having to copy the bash-git-prompt code into a new shell script.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using `bash` 4.x, you can capture it into a variable

```
prompt="${PS1@P}"
```

or just output it for capture into a pipeline

```
echo "${PS1@P}"
```

You can also use `script` to capture a terminal session - including the prompt as displayed - to a file which you can then trim and use for whatever nefarious purposes:

```
$ script foo
user@host:~
$ exit
$ cat foo
Script started on Thu Jul  6 12:59:45 2017
user@host:~
$ exit
exit
Script done on Thu Jul  6 12:59:48 2017
```

Not shown here are all the ANSI color codes which spiff up the prompt.

Comment: i'm on bash 3.2

Comment: @DopeGhoti This doesn't work. I am in bash4.3

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.  `script` is an external tool, so it doesn't care what version of `bash` (or indeed what shell) you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Found a good solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090232/55948

`eval 'echo -en "'$PS1'"'`

Comment: This will not show the expanded prompt.

Comment: you usually go around downvoting 2 year old answers from noobs?? just leave the comment maybe